# Exporting MySQL database from within a command prompt mysql tool. Without mysqldump

Tags: mysql, command-prompt

I am logged into mysql on my server and able to type commands from there. I cannot find the command that will let me export from within the Command Line Tool. Sure I can log out and run `mysqldump -u -p...` but that is a pain. To import from inside the client, you just type `source path/to/the/source`

There must be something like this for export, but everything on the internet points to mysqldump, and so I cannot find the tool I am looking for. After all, mysqldump is just a wrapper for the command that I'm looking for. Does anyone know what to use? Thank you to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After all, mysqldump is just a wrapper for the command that I'm looking for.

No, it actually isn't.

Some of the other utilities like `mysqladmin` and `mysqlcheck` are not much more than "convenient" (or, if you ask me, largely pointless) wrappers for SQL statements you can issue yourself, so I suppose your assumption could be reasonable in that light, but that's not case with `mysqldump`.

The source code for `mysqldump` is ~5,061 lines of C -- and that's *not even including* the code that actually manages the TCP or Unix socket communication with the MySQL server or a lot of other common code libraries that are shared among the MySQL Server and the utilities.

Yes, the `mysqldump` utility does -- where practical -- assemble some SQL statements, send them to the server for execution, and write the server's response in the dump file...

```
my_snprintf(query, sizeof(query), "SHOW CREATE TABLE %s", result_table);
```

... that one's kind of a no-brainer, pretty much a wheel that need not be reinvented.

However, there are a number of operations that it performs that are not at all handled by the MySQL server code.  Examples...

```
if (opt_drop_trigger)
  fprintf(sql_file, "/*!50032 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS %s */;\n", (*show_trigger_row)[0]);

fprintf(sql_file,
      "DELIMITER ;;\n"
      "/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE=\"%s\" */;;\n"
      "/*!50003 CREATE */ ",
      (*show_trigger_row)[6]);
```

There is no functionality inside mysql to do what that does, or this...

```
if (write_data)
{
  if (opt_replace_into)
    dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, "REPLACE ");
  else
    dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, "INSERT ");
  dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, insert_option);
  dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, "INTO ");
  dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, opt_quoted_table);
  if (complete_insert)
  {
    dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, " (");
  }
  else
  {
    dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, " VALUES ");
    if (!extended_insert)
      dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, "(");
  }
}

while ((row= mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
  if (complete_insert)
  {
    if (init)
    {
      dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat, ", ");
    }
    init=1;
    dynstr_append_checked(&insert_pat,
                  quote_name(row[SHOW_FIELDNAME], name_buff, 0));
  }
}
num_fields= mysql_num_rows(result);
mysql_free_result(result);
```

That seems like a lot of unnecessary work for a wrapper. :) You may have worked out by now, that's an example of some of the simple things mysqldump does, reading the row data coming back from the server in a packed binary format after it issues the `SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM ...` to fetch all of the data from each table, and converting it into SQL statements.  The code that actually crafts those `INSERT` statements is from `mysqldump`.  Not in the server.

There's a reason why everything on the Internet points to `mysqldump`.

Comment: Well that certainly does explain why everything was pointing to it. I have not yet fully digested the code you send me, so it might just be me, but it still seems strange that there is no inverse of `source`. While I understand that this might be complex to build it still sees surprising. It is truly the case that I have to log out to dump the DB?

Comment: In any practical sense, yes.  Also, though, talk of "the inverse of `source`" is sort of like attempting division by zero, though... because `source` isn't exactly the opposite of `mysqldump`... you can craft a text file with any kind of arbitrary SQL statements in it and `source` will dutifully send those statements to the server for execution.  Restoring dump files is just one of the things `source` can be used for, while `mysqldump` is specifically for constructing the equivalent SQL statements that would recreate an existing database in exactly its current state.

Answer (score 0):

What `mysqldump` can be achived by different `SHOW` commands and after enough effort you will end up with `mysqldump` ;)

Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show.html for all possible variants.

From my point of view it's more convenient to use `mysqldump` because it takes all the same parameters for connection as `mysql` Command Line Tool.